# pick a sequence of parameters to preserve original convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Suppose for any fixed $\delta >0$, we have
$$X_n(\delta) \overset{\mathbb{P}}\to 0 \quad \text{as}\ \ n \to \infty.$$
Does there exist a sequence $\delta_n \to 0$ such that
$$X_n(\delta_n) \overset{\mathbb{P}}\to 0 \quad \text{as}\ \ n \to \infty?$$

Thank you!

Comment: You can just take $\delta_n=1$ for all $n$? Or do you mean to impose further conditions on the sequence?

Comment: what is $X_n$? otherwise I would say any constant sequence

Comment: sorry, I forgot to impose the condition $\delta \to 0$.

Comment: Sounds like Cantor's diagonal argument.